# public key verification using ca .cer file in python without using m2crypto or openssl

Tags: python, ssl, x509certificate

I want to verify certificate using default python modules. I've `cert.crt` `ca.crt` files.

```
>>ca=x509.load_cert('ca.crt')
>>cert=x509.load_cert('cert.crt')
>>print "verification result: " , cert.verify(cert.get_pkey())
```

How to read certificate, and how to how to verify

Comment: You forgot to mention your problem.